# VirtualBox Windows 2003 64bits Guest on Linux 64 bits Host Network adapter problem

Tags: windows-server-2003, networking, virtualbox, linux, nic

We have successfully installed a window 2003 r2 64bits guest in a Ubuntu 64bits host.  The problem is that we haven't been able to install the Network card.

We already made some attempts to install, like Installing Virtual Box Additions or  Extracting the driver from the additions and trying to install it manually. The card seems to be an AMD PCNet FAST provided by VirtualBox but none of the drivers provided work.  any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does VirtualBox support any other type of card? Try switching if it does.

Comment: yes you are right, it was the only we to overcome the problem. Because we are in a headless environment,before start the guest we need to provide more parameters or switches in the command line: For example:

VBoxManage modifyvm Win2003-R2-64 --nic1 bridged --cableconnected1        on --bridgeadapter1 br0 --nictype1 82540EM

To get more information about different adapters please check:
http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html

Answer (score 0):

are you using KVM or XEN in Ubuntu OS if you using KVM then you must use bridge [networking](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/KVM/Networking) for xen i dont thing so you'll face any issues !!

Comment: Hi actually we are using a headless environment,  anyway we already have a bridge networking configured.  This configuration is working fine with other guesses in the same  host.